# Jetpack Compose text is cut out of column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a simple layout example:

```
Column {
    Row {
        Text("aaa")
        Text("bbb")
        Column {
            //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Text("ccc")
            Text("ddd")
            //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
    }
    Text(text = "eee")
}
```

My problem is that when I uncomment the 2 spacers then the text `eee` disappears. Can someone explain how can the Row take all the space in outer Column by giving weight to inner Spacers? Why isn't the outer Column "protecting" the poor "eee" text?

Comment: Can you please share the image of UI that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to understand the layout process of Jetpack Compose for the above scenario, particularly how spacers work. Instead of spacer, I can use other composables with "fillMaxHeight()" modifier and get the same result. For some reason the inner child deep inside dictates the rules to the outer parent, which I don't like. What I want to achieve is not important, I can achieve it with a different layout.

Comment: After some testing and youtube videos, it turns out that my text is just unlucky to be the last one in column. Seems like the outer column asks the Row to lay itself out, and it takes the whole vertical space because of the inner spacers. So the order in row/column matters when it comes to layout. The parent layout will ask the first child to size itself, then move to the second child with remaining space. If for some reason the first child takes it all, then the second one is doomed to be cut out.

Comment: But fillMaxHeight() will cover the whole column or row

Comment: Can you just send me the UI will provide a better provide code snippet and solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are observing also coincides with what the documentation says about the [`Column`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Column(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)) Composable:

> If at least one child of a Column has a weight, the Column will fill the available height, so there is no need for `Modifier.fillMaxHeight`.

This means that your inner Column will implicitly use `fillMaxHeight`.

> If a child is not provided a weight, it will be asked for its preferred height before the sizes of the children with weights are calculated proportionally to their weight based on the remaining available space.

For children without a weight set, the Column will let themselve choose how much space on the screen they want to consume. As you have observed, it appears like this happens in the order of the children. If one children decides to use all remaining space of the Column, like your inner Column implicitly does, then the other children will be pushed off.

Comment: I have watched some videos from google devs, it seems like this is a result of compose making just 1 pass over the composable tree during the layout stage. Making just 1 pass and asking nodes to lay themselves out makes sense, layout is linear instead of exponential. However, we will have such side effects which are "non-symmetric" relative to the order of the children. If text is first, then it is lucky to claim some space, otherwise it's gone... I wonder how weight works then, maybe it gathers all the weights first and then starts the children pass :)